# Problem with fetching array

Tags: php

Hi my i am having problem with fetching array in the following example.though the result should return row from table but it is returning nothing.it is not entering the while($row=oci_fetch_array($r)) statement,means it's always returning flse,though it should return true..

Comment: What's the value of `oci_fetch_array($r)`?

Answer (score 0):

I think maybe your sql statement is incorrect, you are passing in literally the statement

select n from test where s='{$arr[i]}'

Where you may want to try

$sql="select n from test where s='".$arr[i]."' ";

Separate the php part from the string.

Unless the {} part does that, i am nto that well versed in php =D

Comment: Yes the {} does that.  It is very useful.

Comment: Sweet, well if i ever get back into php looks like i have learnt a new trick :)

Answer (score 0):

I saw

```
while ($row = oci_fetch_array($r, OCI_ASSOC+OCI_RETURN_NULLS))
```

on PHP doc site http://hu.php.net/manual/en/function.oci-execute.php which sounds somewhat better.

Answer (score 0):

There may be something funky going on with your query string. I'd recommend not using parameters instead of embeded strings in your sql.

```
print($sql);
```

Run it against your db in whatever sql tool you use. Do you get results?